# HP G8 migrate RAID0 to RAID1 with CLI commands

Tags: raid1, migration, raid0

This is a Dynamic Smart Array B120i. The SSA (Smart Storage Administrator) is ver 1.50.4.0 The OS was installed into a single hard disc (bay 1), the SSA reports like RAID 0. Then I add a new hard disc into bay 2 (same size disc). I want to use this new hd like mirror of the first.

As you know the GUI SSA dont have a option to migrate this scenario into RAID 1. The CLI commands what I run:

- To create bay2 disc like another RAID 0  (it is necesary?)

  ```
  ctrl slot=0 create type=ld drives=allunassigned
  ```
- This is my command to modify RAID0 into RAID1, but it doesn't work.

  ```
  ctrl slot=0 type=ld modify raid=1
  ```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that with the first command you `create` a new logical drive - when finished you will have two LDs, each containing one disk.

What you need to do instead is add the unassigned disk to the *original* RAID0 LD and then invoke the `modify` command.

In other words:

```
ctrl slot=0 ld=1 add drives=allunassigned
```

And then:

```
ctrl slot=0 ld=1 modify raid=1
```

Also consider increasing the rebuild priority before the above steps with:

```
ctrl slot=0 modify rebuildpriority=high
```

That should work.

Comment: Yep, I was just typing this.

Comment: Nice, when run this commands returns:
ctrl slot=0 ld=1 add drives=allunassigned
message: invalid target syntax "logicaldrive=1" is not a valid target
 Then try this (deleting =)
ctrl slot=0 ld 1 add drives=allunassigned
This operation is not supported with the current configuration.. 
reason: transformation size zero. This may indicate that there is no battery or a failed battery on the controller.

Comment: And have you got a battery there? That seems to be required for array expansions and modifications.

Comment: I dont know, the server comes with OEM features from reseller. I can't activate again the Win2008 key, the only way I see is build Windows mirroring. If is not possible enable RAID1 with SSA, in 3 days I should enable Windows mirror utility.

Comment: Have you got physical access to the server? Can you open it and see if the controller has a battery attached? If not it won't let you do the online conversion from RAID0 to RAID1. That's for making sure that the data won't be damaged in case of a power failure.

Comment: Easiest solution - back up the existing data to an external USB or eSATA drive, rebuild the array as RAID1 and restore the data. That's easier than mucking about with online conversion in many cases.

Comment: I see the server, the B120i is connected to onboard card, back of 4bay try are only cables to board, front haves two screw -should I remove it? I have a TIB image backup of hd (11 gb size image) but the software (cd boot of) Acronis dont let me restore hd attached to server, can restore the hd at other machine only. Buy the TIB image now is old, the system has been changed. I wan to run the CLI commands outline but starting F5 SSA ACU the CLI commands are not availables - F5 is ofline equivalent of SSA?

Comment: The battery is usually quite big (about credit card size and half a centimetre thick), and usually not installed with these low end controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the further info and the fact that the raid controller doesn't have a battery installed I suggest you take a completely different path.

The controller you have - B120i - is not a full hardware RAID, it's more like a hardware assisted software RAID. There is very little advantage in using these "FakeRAID" cards over pure software RAIDs. It's not any faster and is less flexible.

So to solve your problem I would do the following:

- Install the 2nd disk and present it a s normal disk (non-RAID) to the OS
- Create a *degraded RAID1 array* on that one disk - degraded means that one of the two RAID1 disks is missing, that's fine.
- Copy everything across from the original disk to the new one.
- Boot from the new one
- Remove the old RAID0 array, present the 1st disk to the OS
- Attach it to the software RAID1 array and let it synchronise.

Job done :)

Comment: Thank you, this metod is a creative path, I'll work on it.

Comment: Cool, give it a try and report back if you need any further help. In the meantime I would appreciate if you could tick one of the answers as correct to award the points for the time spent helping you. Cheers!

Comment: Talking with manager we take the alternative of adquire an Adaptec or LSI card. Thanks to all forums guys by support us.